# pythonのmechanizeで応答がない

Tags: python, mechanize

以下のスクリプトを実行すると、応答が返ってきません。

```
import mechanize

b = mechanize.Browser();
b.set_handle_robots(False);
h = b.open('http://stocks.finance.yahoo.co.jp/stocks/detail/?code=2726');
```

他のurl(`http://www.google.com`など)ではちゃんと応答が返ってきます。
なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

株価情報ですので定期的にrefreshがかかることが原因かと思います。
Refreshヘッダを無効化するため、`set_handle_refresh(False)`を指定してください。
応答が返ることを確認しました。

```
import mechanize

b = mechanize.Browser()
b.set_handle_robots(False)
b.set_handle_refresh(False)
h = b.open('http://stocks.finance.yahoo.co.jp/stocks/detail/?code=2726')
```

細かいですが、pythonは`;`は不要です。
あってもエラーにはなりませんが･･･

Comment: うまくいきました。ありがとうございました。